# While inserting there are more then 1 item

Tags: sql

There is a User Table.

```
Id    Name    Surname     Address     OID
1     n1      s1          a1          24
2     n2      s2          a2          24
3     n3      s3          a3          24
4     n4      s4          a4          12
```

I want to duplicate rows where OID = 24. I wrote below query but I got error.

```
INSERT INTO [User] ([OID],[Name],[Surname],[Address]) SELECT * FROM [User] Where OID = 24
```

**Error:**

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the
>   insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of
>   INSERT columns.

How can Insert these rows w/o error? Also I dont know how many records will return from `SELECT` statement, sometimes it can be 1 sometimes 5, sometimes 15 etc.

Comment: First of all I had no idea you could even do that. Secondly, instead of using * you may want to specify the columns in the exact order.

Comment: The number of columns you are inserting into do not match the number of columns you are selecting.

Comment: yes you are right this is completely my mistake..

Comment: I dont know what were the reasons..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    INSERT INTO [User] ([OID],[Name],[Surname],[Address])  
    SELECT [OID],[Name],[Surname],[Address] FROM [User] Where OID = 24
```

your `select *`  is retrieving 5 `fields`, but you only can `insert` 4.
So, you must the `fields` to insert

Answer (score 4):

If you do not specify the columns in the select, all of them will come, including `Id`, which is not specified in the `insert` command.

Here's what you should do:

```
INSERT INTO [User] ([OID],[Name],[Surname],[Address]) 
SELECT              [OID],[Name],[Surname],[Address] 
FROM [User] Where OID = 24
```

Now, forgive my frankness, but the error message is pretty self explanatory, actually.

Answer (score 1):

You have too many columns in your `SELECT` statement, since you are using `SELECT *`.  You should specify the columns that you are selecting:

```
INSERT INTO [User] ([OID],[Name],[Surname],[Address]) 
SELECT OID, name, Surname, Address 
FROM [User] 
Where OID = 24
```

This is why specifying the columns that you want is better than using `SELECT *`

When you `SELECT *` you are also getting the `Id` field but you are not including that in your `INSERT INTO` portion of the query.